# Using in-memory UIWebView to generate PDF in PhoneGap

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, cordova, pdf-generation

I'm trying to work out how to do this.

NOTE: I'm not an experienced objective-c developer (hence why I'm using PhoneGap in the first place)

**The short of it**: My UIWebView (no, not the PhoneGap one that renders the webapp, a 2nd UIWebView created in-memory and not visible) is not rendering into the PDF. I just get an blank PDF. I'll post some of my thinking and code, and hopefully someone will know what I'm doing wrong.

---

My starting place is that there is already a print plugin for PhoneGap here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/PrintPlugin

This plugin creates a UIWebView on-the-fly, you pass some HTML to it via JavaScript, and then it calls some print controller to do the printing.

So I borrowed some ideas from that. Then I noticed this awesome blog post on generating PDF's

http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/

So I'm trying to combine the two into my own PhoneGap plugin for taking some HTML (from my webapp) and generating a PDF on-the-fly.

HEADER:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
#import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
#else
#import "PGPlugin.h"
#endif


@interface ExportPlugin : PGPlugin <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    NSString* exportHTML;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* exportHTML;

//This gets called from my HTML5 app (Javascript):
- (void) exportPdf:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

MAIN:

```
#import "ExportPlugin.h"

@interface ExportPlugin (Private)
-(void) doExport;
-(void) drawPdf;
@end

@implementation ExportPlugin

@synthesize exportHTML;

- (void) exportPdf:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options{
    NSUInteger argc = [arguments count];

    if (argc < 1) {
        return; 
    }
    self.exportHTML = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    [self doExport];
}

int imageName = 0;
double webViewHeight = 0.0;

- (void) doExport{
    //Set the base URL to be the www directory.
    NSString *dbFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www" ofType:nil ];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dbFilePath];

    //Load custom html into a webview 
    UIWebView *webViewExport = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    webViewExport.delegate = self;
    //[webViewExport loadHTMLString:exportHTML baseURL:baseURL];
    [webViewExport loadHTMLString:@"<html><body><h1>testing</h1></body></html>" baseURL:baseURL];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewExport
{        
    webViewHeight = [[webViewExport stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] integerValue];

    CGRect screenRect = webViewExport.frame;

    //WHY DO I HAVE TO SET THE SIZE? OTHERWISE IT IS 0
    screenRect.size.width = 768;
    screenRect.size.height = 1024;

    double currentWebViewHeight = webViewHeight;
    while (currentWebViewHeight > 0)
    {
        imageName ++;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        //[[UIColor blackColor] set];
        //CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

        [webViewExport.layer renderInContext:ctx];

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageName]];

        if(currentWebViewHeight < 960)
        {
            CGRect lastImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 960 - currentWebViewHeight, webViewExport.frame.size.width, currentWebViewHeight);
            CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([newImage CGImage], lastImageRect);    

            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
            CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        }
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

        [webViewExport stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollBy(0,960);"];

        currentWebViewHeight -= 960;
    }

    [self drawPdf];
}

- (void) drawPdf
{
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, webViewHeight);
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    double currentHeight = 0.0;
    for (int index = 1; index  <= imageName ; index++)
    {
        NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", index]];
        UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];

        [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height)];
        currentHeight += pngImage.size.height;
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}

@end
```

The first indication something is not right, is above I have to set the UIWebView.frame size:

```
screenRect.size.width = 768;
screenRect.size.height = 1024;
```

But why? The PhoneGap PrintPlugin doesn't have to do this. If I don't set it, the size is 0, and then I get lots of context errors.

And then the next problem is that the UIWebView is not rendering anything. A symptom of the first problem perhaps?

How do I go about debugging this and working out what the problem is?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm pretty sure that it may be impossible to render the UIWebView layer into the image context, unless that UIWebView is actually visible.

I'm not sure how the PhoneGap PrintPlugin works then. It seems to render it's UIWebView quite fine with it not being visible.

I'm currently experimenting with rendering the actual PhoneGap UIWebView into the PDF (as opposed to my own UIWebView). But this is not ideal.

- It means I have to hide all toolbars and whatnot, and then *pan* the UIWebView around so I capture everything outside the viewport. This is not ideal, because the user will visually see this occurring!
- Point 1 above doesn't seem to work anyway, because iPad is too slow to update the screen when dynamically fiddling with the layout. On iPad, if you do visual things very quickly, (like panning the screen around) the iPad is too slow and just wont show it. You end up only seeing the end state. So when I take the screenshots, the screen visually hasn't panned (even though the DOM says it has). (Hope that makes sense).

Agh, frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a working solution now, but it's not ideal.

What I do is render the phonegap UIWebView into the PDF.

To do this is quite tricky. I have a couple of objective-c functions

```
- (void) takeScreenshot;

- (void) renderPdf;
```

that I call from Javascript.

Then I have to write a recursive JS algorithm that pans the screen in every direction whilst calling `takeScreenshot`.

In between calls to `takeScreenshot` I use `setTimeout` which gives a 20 millisecond break in the JS processing - enough time for the iPad to update the screen so the next screenshot can be taken.

It was a royal pain in the arse. Bounty is still open in case someone knows of a better way of dealing with this - I would be very curious to know!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a UIWebView into a PDF, I think you could go for this :

1/ use the convertRect:fromView method implemented by your UIWebView object to get the CGRect

2/ see the [UIPrintPageRenderer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIPrintPageRenderer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to make like a print preview

3/ Use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext to get the CGContextRef out of it

4/ create the PDF from the CGRect and CGContextRef (you can use the help provided in the Apple [sample code zoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/) for building PDF using CGPdf

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to render PDF in a UIWebView (webPage being your UIWebView), your delegate (here "self") could implement the UIWebViewDelegate protocol :

```
- (void)loadingPDFwithURL:(NSURL *)anURL {
    CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    appFrame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.webPage initWithFrame:appFrame];
    [self.webPage setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self.webPage setDelegate:self];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:anURL];
    [self.webPage loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webPage];
}
```

So you're giving the URL of the PDF (if it's in memory, just write the file in your application as the URL can be a filepath).

Another possibility is to dive into CGPdf but it's getting harder.

Comment: I actually need the opposite - rendering the contents of a UIWebView into a PDF